# python pandas AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'head'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
df = pd.read_excel(download_path, sheet_name=None)
l = df.values.tolist()
```

on this I am getting error **uiltin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'tolist'**

when I do something like this

```
  print(df.head())
```

I get error like  **AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'head'**

what thing I am doing wrong here ?

version of libraries

pandas==1.5.1
openpyxl
xlrd==2.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading an excel file with pandas, if you set `sheet_name=None` as a parameter for `pd.read_excel` you will get a dictionary mapping between sheet names in the excel file and their corresponding `DataFrame`s (as hinted in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#:%7E:text=None%3A%20All%20worksheets)).

You can use the following template to extract the relevant `DataFrame`s

```python
mapping = pd.read_excel(download_path, sheet_name=None)
for sheet_name in mapping:
    df = mapping[sheet_name]
    l = df.values.tolist()
```

Comment: can I use get sheet names ? what you are referring as  mapping ?

Comment: Hi @tousifNoor, I fixed the variable name on the first line. If you want to get the sheet names, you can call mapping.keys() or just iterate over mapping like in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to avoid this error is passing index_col argument to read_excel method.

```
from pandas import read_excel
df = read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name=None)
df.head()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'head'

df = read_excel("file.xlsx", index_col=None)
df.head()
   col. 0     col. 1     col. 2     col. 3     col. 4
0  row. 1  value 1.1  value 2.1  value 3.1  value 4.1
1  row. 2  value 1.2  value 2.2  value 3.2  value 4.2
2  row. 3  value 1.3  value 2.3  value 3.3  value 4.3
3  row. 4  value 1.4  value 2.4  value 3.4  value 4.4
4  row. 5  value 1.5  value 2.5  value 3.5  value 4.5
```